# I have created a table in rails using the migration file. But I am not able to access the table in the rails console

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have created a table called as Flowlogs in the rails application using the migration file. I've also fed the data to that table in the rails console. All of a sudden when I try to manually feed the data in the rails console then I get the error.

I've created a table named "flowlogs" and there are two columns in the table with the names vpc_id and flowlog_id.
    I've logged into the rails console and gave a=Flowlogs.new() and then a.vpc_id="1234" and a.flowlog_id="a1234" and finally gave a.save. This has successfully worked and I have cross-checked using by using the command Flowlogs.all. It has shown the output. But after sometime when I logged into the console and gave Flowlogs.all, then it kept throwing the errors.

Most importantly when I logged into the mysql console and checked there is a table with the data with I fed manually in the rails console

My database name is fusion.

```
    Flowlog Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `flowlog`.* FROM `flowlog`
    Hirb Error: Mysql2::Error: Table 'fusion.flowlog' doesn't exist: SELECT `flowlog`.* FROM `flowlog`
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `_query'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:120:in `block in query'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `handle_interrupt'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:119:in `query'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `block in execute'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `execute'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:231:in `execute'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:235:in `exec_query'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:356:in `select'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:639:in `exec_queries'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:515:in `load'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `to_ary'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/hirb-0.7.3/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:88:in `Array'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/hirb-0.7.3/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:88:in `determine_output_class'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/hirb-0.7.3/lib/hirb/formatter.rb:53:in `format_output'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/hirb-0.7.3/lib/hirb/view.rb:205:in `render_output'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/hirb-0.7.3/lib/hirb/view.rb:123:in `view_output'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/hirb-0.7.3/lib/hirb/view.rb:201:in `view_or_page_output'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/hirb-0.7.3/lib/hirb/view.rb:187:in `output_value'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:490:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:623:in `signal_status'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:486:in `block in eval_input'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:246:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `loop'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `catch'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `each_top_level_statement'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:485:in `eval_input'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:395:in `block in start'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:394:in `catch'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:394:in `start'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        /Users/masettya/fusion_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        /Users/masettya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        -e:1:in `<main>'
```

This is my migration file

```
    class CreateFlowlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :flowlogs do |t|
            t.string :account_name
            t.string :region
            t.string :vpc_id
            t.string :flowlog_id
            t.boolean :status
        end
      end
    end
```

This is the schema.rb file

```
create_table "account_master", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name",         limit: 52,               null: false
    t.string "alias_name",   limit: 52,               null: false
    t.string "owner",        limit: 26,               null: false
    t.string "mail_contact", limit: 100
    t.string "dl_email",     limit: 50
    t.string "root_user",    limit: 32,               null: false
    t.string "team",         limit: 32
    t.string "contact_no",   limit: 15
    t.string "email",        limit: 50
    t.string "del_flg",      limit: 1,   default: "", null: false
    t.date   "created_on",                            null: false
    t.string "created_by",   limit: 50
    t.date   "modified_on"
    t.string "modified_by",  limit: 50
    t.string "account_type", limit: 50
    t.string "ssl_account",  limit: 20
  end

  create_table "admin_authentication_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",              limit: 255,   default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password", limit: 255,   default: "",    null: false
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",      limit: 4,     default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip", limit: 255
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip",    limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "uid",                limit: 255
    t.text     "all_details",        limit: 65535
    t.string   "otp_secret_key",     limit: 255
    t.boolean  "qr_not_required",                  default: false, null: false
    t.boolean  "active",                           default: false, null: false
    t.boolean  "deleted",                          default: false, null: false
  end

  add_index "admin_authentication_users", ["email"], name: "index_admin_authentication_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "employee_shift", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "emp_id",       limit: 30
    t.string   "session",      limit: 50
    t.string   "created_by",   limit: 100
    t.datetime "created_on"
    t.date     "session_date"
    t.string   "emp_name",     limit: 200
    t.string   "updated_by",   limit: 200
    t.datetime "updated_on"
  end

  create_table "flowlogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "account_name", limit: 255
    t.string  "region",       limit: 255
    t.string  "vpc_id",       limit: 255
    t.string  "flowlog_id",   limit: 255
    t.boolean "status"
  end

  create_table "tests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "function",    limit: 255
    t.string "description", limit: 255
  end

  create_table "updates", primary_key: "reference_id", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "created_by",    limit: 200,   default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_on",                               null: false
    t.string   "subject",       limit: 2000,  default: "", null: false
    t.text     "body_content",  limit: 65535,              null: false
    t.string   "status",        limit: 20,    default: "", null: false
    t.string   "creted_by_id",  limit: 100,   default: "", null: false
    t.string   "account",       limit: 100,   default: "", null: false
    t.string   "archive_by",    limit: 200
    t.datetime "archive_on"
    t.string   "archive_by_id", limit: 200
  end

end
```

Comment: `flowlog` != `flowlogs`

Comment: I have tried both flowlog and flowlogs to test, nothing worked @FrankerZ

Comment: Can you post your schema.rb? Also, can you retry your commands with `save!` instead of `save` and see if an error is raised? And your db:migrate command hasn't shown any errors?

Comment: I have shared the schema.rb for your understanding, can you please help me out now @JayDorsey

Comment: @MasettyAbhishek take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19937578/2892779 The issue might be caused because you've pluralized the flowlogs model, but the table it's looking for is `flowlog`. On Rails3, idk what mixing the two up will do but newer versions of rails are pretty good about automatically pluralizing/singularizing the model & table name for you. AFAIK, the recommended way is singular Model name, creates a pluralized table name.  I'd probably make sure your model is singular Flowlog (flowlog.rb) and see if that fixes it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Table doesn't exist error, but the table does exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Mysql2::Error: Table doesn't exist)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937286/getting-table-doesnt-exist-error-but-the-table-does-exist-activerecordstate)